# Marklogic Insert simple url containing &fm=1, getting "invalid entity reference" exception error

Tags: exception, insert, marklogic

I have a problem when insert just as simple text file which contains below URL: http://www.abcxyz.com/it/u=1583561411,276132887&fm=1

However, I got **"invalid entity reference"** exception error at **fm=1**.
I already using xdmp:unquote.

Anybody know how to solve it.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide sample code? The following works fine: `xdmp:document-insert(
  '/foo1.txt',
  text { 'Here is a URL: http://www.abcxyz.com/it/u=1583561411,276132887&amp;fm=1' }
)`

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `xdmp:unquote` for what you are doing.  `xdmp:unquote` is for converting text into xml, which is not what you are trying to do.  Is there a reason you are using `xdmp:unquote`?

Comment: Thank you Dave Cassel and CtheGood8.
Following your guidance, I can insert the text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XQuery uses XML entity syntax in strings and nodes, so `&` is an invalid entity reference. You can use ampersands in your XQuery code by replacing `&` with `&amp;`.

Note: in XQuery and XML, you additionally have to escape `>` (`&gt;`) and `<` (`&lt;`).

Comment: Thank you, Joemfb.
I already change &-->&amp;
However, the same error is threw.